# Keras: Tensor object has no attribute "_keras_history"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Most of the answers to [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45313408/keras-custom-layer-attributeerror-tensor-object-has-no-attribute-keras-hi) previous questions have suggested wrapping the problematic tensor in a `Lambda` layer. I've already done this, however (and tried many variations on the fix), and it's still throwing the same error.
Pseudocode for my current model definition looks like this:

```py
# [previous layers of model definition not shown here for simplicity]
out_duration = Reshape((30, 3))(out_duration)
out_position = Reshape((30, 3))(out_position)
low = tf.constant([(30x3) numpy array of lower bounds)]) # can't use K.clip here because the lower bound is different for every element
high = tf.constant([(30x3) numpy array of upper bounds)])
clipped_out_position = Lambda(lambda x: tf.clip_by_value(*x), output_shape=out_position.get_shape().as_list())([out_position, low, high])
model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=[out_duration, clipped_out_position]
```

Error output:

```py
   File "multitask_inverter.py", line 107, in <module>
    main()
  File "multitask_inverter.py", line 75, in main
    model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=[out_duration, clipped_out_position])
  File "/om/user/lnj/openmind_env/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 88, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/om/user/lnj/openmind_env/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 1705, in __init__
    build_map_of_graph(x, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress)
  File "/om/user/lnj/openmind_env/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 1695, in build_map_of_graph
    layer, node_index, tensor_index)
  File "/om/user/lnj/openmind_env/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 1665, in build_map_of_graph
    layer, node_index, tensor_index = tensor._keras_history
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide `low` and `high` to the layer with `Lambda(..., arguments={'low': low, 'high': high})`. From the documentation of `Lambda`:

> arguments: optional dictionary of keyword arguments to be passed to
>   the function.

For example,

```
clipped_out_position = Lambda(lambda x, low, high: tf.clip_by_value(x, low, high),
                              arguments={'low': low, 'high': high})(out_position)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Here's a more complete sample on testing this layer:

```
x = Input(shape=(100,))
out_duration = Dense(90)(x)
out_position = Dense(90)(x)
out_duration = Reshape((30, 3))(out_duration)
out_position = Reshape((30, 3))(out_position)

low = tf.constant(np.random.rand(30, 3).astype('float32'))
high = tf.constant(1 + np.random.rand(30, 3).astype('float32'))
clipped_out_position = Lambda(lambda x, low, high: tf.clip_by_value(x, low, high),
                              arguments={'low': low, 'high': high})(out_position)

model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=[out_duration, clipped_out_position])
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(np.random.rand(5000, 100), [np.random.rand(5000, 30, 3), np.random.rand(5000, 30, 3)])
```

Comment: This results in a `ValueError: No data provided for "lambda_1". Need data for each key in: ['out_duration', 'lambda_1']` -- I'm not entirely sure what's going on here.

Comment: I think you need to post more code. The new problem does not come from the code you've posted. How's your model look like and how do you call `fit()`?

Comment: I've added an example network on how to use this line. Can you compare it with your network and check if there's any difference? It seems to me that your error is a different problem than the original one, since it's an error raised from `fit()`, not model construction.

Comment: Awesome, it works! Can you explain why adding the `arguments` param was the right fix for this case?

Comment: I think that's because `low` and `high` are not Keras tensors. A Keras tensor records some topological information in `_keras_history`. When the information is not found during model building, you'll see an error like that. To pass something that's not the output of a Keras layer to a `Lambda` layer, the `arguments` parameter can be used.