# Tensor object has no attribute _keras_history

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, torch, named-entity-recognition

can any one please help me resolve this problem:

[image: Error screenshot]

> AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history'

I found the code [on github](https://github.com/malihasameen/named-entity-recognition/blob/master/NER.ipynb).

Comment: What is the version of Python and TF you using? Also there are many posts on the same topic. Did you go over those? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44889187/attributeerror-tensor-object-has-no-attribute-keras-history https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47025750/keras-tensor-object-has-no-attribute-keras-history

Comment: Yes I have checked related posts and tried to solve but couldn't work.
I am using google colab environment 
python version 3.6 and 
tensorflow version =2.5

Comment: hey mario, welcome to SO. Please don't post error messages as screenshots. That makes it impossible for search engines to index them and makes your post inacessible to many users with disabilities, just to name a few reasons

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Several workarounds are mentioned in this thread take a look https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/7362