# Issue with Keras backend flatten

Tags: tensorflow, keras, flatten

Why does Keras.backend.flatten not show proper dimension? I have the following:

x is <tf.Tensor 'concat_8:0' shape=(?, 4, 8, 62) dtype=float32>

After:

```
Keras.backend.flatten(x)
```

x becomes: <tf.Tensor 'Reshape_22:0' **shape=(?,)** dtype=float32>

**Why is x not of shape=(?, 4*8*62)**

**EDIT-1**

I get (?, ?) if I use `batch_flatten` (`branch3x3` & `branch5x5` below are tensors from previous convolutions):

```
x = Lambda(lambda v: K.concatenate([v[0], v[1]], axis=3))([branch3x3, branch5x5])
x = Lambda(lambda v: K.batch_flatten(v))(x)
```

Result of first Lambda is <tf.Tensor 'lambda_144/concat:0' shape=(?, 4, 8, 62) dtype=float32>

Result of second Lambda is <tf.Tensor 'lambda_157/Reshape:0' shape=(?, ?) dtype=float32>

**EDIT-2**

Tried `batch_flatten` but get an error downstream when I build the model output (using `reshape` instead of `batch_flatten` seems to work). `branch3x3` is <tf.Tensor 'conv2d_202/Elu:0' shape=(?, 4, 8, 30) dtype=float32>, and `branch5x5` is <tf.Tensor 'conv2d_203/Elu:0' shape=(?, 4, 8, 32) dtype=float32>:

```
from keras import backend as K
x = Lambda(lambda v: K.concatenate([v[0], v[1]], axis=3))([branch3x3, branch5x5])
x = Lambda(lambda v: K.batch_flatten(v))(x)
y = Conv1D(filters=2, kernel_size=4)(Input(shape=(4, 1)))
y = Lambda(lambda v: K.batch_flatten(v))(y)
z = Lambda(lambda v: K.concatenate([v[0], v[1]], axis=1))([x, y])
output = Dense(32, kernel_initializer=TruncatedNormal(), activation='linear')(z)
cnn = Model(inputs=[m1, m2], outputs=output)
```

The `output` statement results in the following error for the `kernel_initializer`: **TypeError: Failed to convert object of type  to Tensor. Contents: (None, 32). Consider casting elements to a supported type.**

Comment: Please check if your code is executable before posting it. It's hard to reproduce the error when the code is wrong. You're calling `K.concatenate([v[0], v[1], v[2]], axis=3)` with only two inputs `[branch3x3, branch5x5]`.

Comment: Also, is there a reason to use `Lambda` layers instead of the `Concatenate` and `Flatten` layers implemented in Keras?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. My real code is longer, so stripped it down here to focus on the main issues. Am using the Lambda layer for creating the model based on your advice in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45309236/keras-backend-modeling-issue  (was facing a similar issue as in that case)

Comment: I've edited and added an example to make it clear :). Please see if that works for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the docstring of `flatten`:

```py
def flatten(x):
    """Flatten a tensor.
    # Arguments
        x: A tensor or variable.
    # Returns
        A tensor, reshaped into 1-D
    """
```

So it turns a tensor with shape `(batch_size, 4, 8, 62)` into a 1-D tensor with shape `(batch_size * 4 * 8 * 62,)`. That's why your new tensor has a 1-D shape `(?,)`.

If you want to keep the first dimension, use `batch_flatten`:

```py
def batch_flatten(x):
    """Turn a nD tensor into a 2D tensor with same 0th dimension.
    In other words, it flattens each data samples of a batch.
    # Arguments
        x: A tensor or variable.
    # Returns
        A tensor.
    """
```

---

**EDIT:** You see the shape being `(?, ?)` because the shape is determined dynamically at runtime. If you feed in a numpy array, you can easily verify that the shape is correct.

```py
input_tensor = Input(shape=(4, 8, 62))
x = Lambda(lambda v: K.batch_flatten(v))(input_tensor)
print(x)

Tensor("lambda_1/Reshape:0", shape=(?, ?), dtype=float32)

model = Model(input_tensor, x)
out = model.predict(np.random.rand(32, 4, 8, 62))
print(out.shape)

(32, 1984)
```

---

**EDIT-2:**

From the error message, it seems that `TruncatedNormal` requires a fixed output shape from the previous layer. So the dynamic shape `(None, None)` from `batch_flatten` won't work.

I can think of two options:

1. Provide manually computed `output_shape` to the `Lambda` layers:

```py
x = Lambda(lambda v: K.concatenate([v[0], v[1]], axis=3))([branch3x3, branch5x5])
x_shape = (np.prod(K.int_shape(x)[1:]),)
x = Lambda(lambda v: K.batch_flatten(v), output_shape=x_shape)(x)

input_y = Input(shape=(4, 1))
y = Conv1D(filters=2, kernel_size=4)(input_y)
y_shape = (np.prod(K.int_shape(y)[1:]),)
y = Lambda(lambda v: K.batch_flatten(v), output_shape=y_shape)(y)

z = Lambda(lambda v: K.concatenate([v[0], v[1]], axis=1))([x, y])
output = Dense(32, kernel_initializer=TruncatedNormal(), activation='linear')(z)
cnn = Model(inputs=[m1, m2, input_y], outputs=output)
```

2. Use the `Flatten` layer (which calls `batch_flatten` and computes the output shape inside of it):

```py
x = Concatenate(axis=3)([branch3x3, branch5x5])
x = Flatten()(x)

input_y = Input(shape=(4, 1))
y = Conv1D(filters=2, kernel_size=4)(input_y)
y = Flatten()(y)

z = Concatenate(axis=1)([x, y])
output = Dense(32, kernel_initializer=TruncatedNormal(), activation='linear')(z)
cnn = Model(inputs=[m1, m2, input_y], outputs=output)
```

I'd prefer the latter as it makes the code less cluttered. Also,

- You can replace the `Lambda` layer wrapping `K.concatenate()` with a `Concatenate` layer.
- Remember to move the `Input(shape=(4, 1))` out and provide it in your `Model(inputs=...)` call.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will try out the Flatten() option. Using `reshape` also seems to work: `x = Lambda(lambda v: K.reshape(v, (-1, product_of_dimensions)))(x)`